# C# Cannot implicitly convert from type 'T' to type 'T'

Tags: c#, generics, implicit-conversion

I get the error message "cannot implicitly convert from type 'SpecificT' to type 'The.Right.Namespace.SpecificT' in the method ToViewDocument.

It seems that in this method I'm redefining the type SpecificT.

This is the methods that gives me troubles:

```
public override SpecifiedT 
ToViewDocument<SpecifiedT>(XmlEntity entity, DocKey docKey)
    {
        switch (docKey.IdArchive)
        {
            case IdArchive.A:
                return ToAViewData((XmlDocA)entity, docKey) //error at this line;
            default:
                return ToBViewData((XmlDocB)entity, docKey) //error at this line;
        }
    }

private SpecifiedT ToAViewData(XmlDocMassima entity, DocKey documentKey)
    {
        SpecifiedT result = new SpecifiedT();
       //map result on entity result
       //...
       return result;
    }
```

that function overrides the base class' method:

```
public abstract T ToViewDocument<T>(XmlEntity entity, DocKey documentKey) where T : ViewDocumentDto, new();
```

Moreover SpecifiedT extends T so I can't understand why the compiler cannot recognize SpecifiedT as a subclass of T.

Comment: What do the containing class definitions look like ?

Comment: You want `SpecifiedT` is an actual class ? Or do you intend it to be a type parameter ?

Comment: In `ToViewDocument` `SpecifiedT` is a type parameter, but in `ToAViewData` it appears to be a concrete class? If so, this will never work since it's the client that chooses `SpecifiedT` when calling `ToViewDocument` e.g. `ToViewDocument<string>(entity, docKey)`.

Comment: You may need to specify a `where T : class, new()` in the generic definition

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir
 SpecifiedT and its base class T are simple classes containing only properties:

    public class SpecifiedT : T{
     public string Prop1 {get;set;}
     public string Prop2 {get;set;}
     public string Prop3 {get;set;}
     ...
    }

Comment: You can't change method signature on override for _generic method_. Did you mean it to be generic class? If latter, you don't need <T> after method name.

Comment: Looks like you have a naming conflict between your class `SpecifiedT` and a generic parameter name `SpecifiedT`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't override a generic method and specify the type parameter. You could add the type parameter to the containing class. Then when you implement the class the type parameter will be set to the concrete type.

```
abstract class Container<T>
    where T : ViewDocumentDto, new()
{
    public abstract T ToViewDocument(XmlEntity entity, DocKey documentKey);
}

class SpecificContainer : Container<SpecificViewDocumentDto>
{
    public override SpecificViewDocumentDto ToViewDocument(XmlEntity entity, DocKey documentKey)
    {
    }
}
```